# Program is not saving to the next space available

Tags: java, arrays

The problem I have encountered is as follows:  I have created two arrays representing docking spaces for ships. The first array the ship object (shipName and size - usually Super-Container) can be saved in the array and if there is no space then it will be added to a waiting list array.

I can only add one ship to the waiting list and it says it is full.
Can you help? Here's my dock class, problem in waitingList():

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
private static Ship[] dock1 = new Ship[10];
private static Ship[] waitingList = new Ship[10];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    menu();
}

public static void menu() {


    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


    while (true) {

        System.out.println("Choose an option: 1-3");
        System.out.println("1. Dock");
        System.out.println("2. Undock");
        System.out.println("3. Status");

        int menu = scan.nextInt();
        switch (menu) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("1. Dock");
                dock();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("2. Undock");
                undock();
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("3. Status");
                printDock();
                printWaitingList();
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("4. Exit");
                System.exit(0);
            default:
                System.out.println("No such option");
                break;
        }
    }
}


public static void dock() {

    System.out.println("Enter ship's name: ");
    String name = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter ship's size: ");
    String size = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter the ships dock:");
    //Check if the dock number is valid
    int i = Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());
    if (i >= 0 && i < 10 && dock1[i] == null) {
        int c = 0;
        int co = 0;
        int sco = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < dock1.length; j++) {
            if (dock1[j] != null &&         dock1[j].getShipSize().equals("Cargo")) {
                c++;
            }
            if (dock1[j] != null && dock1[j].getShipSize().equals("Container")) {
                co++;
            }
            if (dock1[j] != null && dock1[j].getShipSize().equals("Super-Container")) {
                sco++;
            }
        }

        if (c < 10 && co < 5 && sco < 2) {
            //Add ship to the dock
            dock1[i] = new Ship(name, size);
            System.out.println("Enough space you can dock");
            System.out.println("Ship has been docked");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You cannot dock");
            waitingList(name,size);
        }

    } else {
        System.out.println("Couldn't dock");
        waitingList(name, size);
    }

}


public static void undock() {
    System.out.println("Status of ships: ");
    printDock();
    System.out.println("Enter ship's name to undock: ");
    String name = scan.nextLine();
    //System.out.println("Enter ship's size to undock: ");
   // String size = scan.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < dock1.length; i++) {
        if (dock1[i] != null && dock1[i].getShipName().equals(name)) {
            dock1[i] = null;
            System.out.println("Ship removed");
            /// HERE CHECK IF SHIP IN DOCK
            for (int j = 0; j < waitingList.length; j++) {
                if (dock1[i] == null) {
                    // Add ship to the dock
                    dock1[i] = new Ship(waitingList[j].getShipName(), waitingList[j].getShipSize());
                    System.out.println("Move ship from waiting list to dock 1");
                    waitingList[j] = null;
                   break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No space in dock1");
                    return;
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Ship not docked here");
            break;
        }

    }

}

public static void waitingList(String name, String size){
    System.out.println("Dock 1 is full, ship will try to be added to Waiting List");
    for (int i = 0; i < waitingList.length; i++) {
        if (waitingList[i] == null) { //CHANGE TO ALLOW MORE THAN ONE SHIP
            //Add ship to the dock
            waitingList[i] = new Ship(name, size);
            System.out.println("Enough space added to waiting list");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("No space on waiting list, ship turned away");
            return;
        }
    }

}


public static void printDock() {

    System.out.println("Docks:");

    for (int i = 0; i < dock1.length; i++) {
        if (dock1[i] == null) {
            System.out.println("Dock " + i + " is empty");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Dock " + i + ": " + dock1[i].getShipName() + " " + dock1[i].getShipSize());
        }
    }
}

private static void printWaitingList() {

    System.out.println("Waiting List:");

    for (int i = 0; i < waitingList.length; i++) {
        if (waitingList[i] == null) {
            System.out.println("Dock " + i + " is empty");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Dock " + i + ": " + waitingList[i].getShipName() + " " + waitingList[i].getShipSize());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are asking. Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Once the first array is full the object gets added to the second array (waitingList[]), but it can only add one object then it says it is full. It should be able to add 10 objects but can only add one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void waitingList(String name, String size){
    System.out.println("Dock 1 is full, ship will try to be added to Waiting List");
     for (int i = 0; i < waitingList.length; i++) {
         if (waitingList[i] == null) {
                //Add ship to the dock
                waitingList[i] = new Ship(name, size);
                System.out.println("Enough space. Added to waiting list.");
                return;
         } else {
                System.out.println("No space on waiting list at number "+ i +", checking next space."); //Optional
         }
     }
     // Only when no spaces available
     System.out.println("No space on waiting list, ship turned away.");
}
```

if you add a ship to the `waitingList` array, it will not be null never again, so that check (`if waitingList[0] == null`) will result into executing the else part, where it is a `return`, so the loop will not continue and will never try to check `if waitingList[1] == null`.

So, the solution is to exit the method when the ship is added to the list, not when we see the first used space. So changeing the `return` will help.

Comment: Yeah thank you, I know where the problem was just didn't know how to change it to allow more than one object

Comment: @S.smith94 just delete the return, and the loop will keep going. If it was helpfull remember check it as correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: That does work in adding but it keeps kicking itself of the loop. I need something to change in the if statement

Comment: @S.smith94 I forgot to add the return in the if true part. Check it now. The if condition is right.

Comment: No matter what I do I keep getting                                                       "No space on waiting list, ship turned away
Enough space added to waiting list"

Comment: it should only say "Enough space added to waiting list"

Comment: Something needs to change inside  if (waitingList[i] == null)

Comment: @S.smith94 You get "no space" because it checks the first one, then the next one, until it reaches the empty one. Just change the print to this: System.out.println("No space on waiting list at number "+ i +", checking next space."); If you want to display it ONLY when there are NO empty spaces you should boolean the contition. Let me do it.

Comment: @S.smith94 Check it now. There is an optional print that you may not like to appear.

Comment: This is perfect thank you very much! I appreciate it.